# After installing k8s1.26.2 using kubeadm, all pods including etcd,kube-proxy are in the crashloopbackoff state

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I am trying to install k8s1.26 on debian11, my kernel version is 5.10.0/x86_64.
Here is my kubelet logs.

```
Mar 09 17:51:55 devnew0 kubelet[369024]: I0309 17:51:55.933659  369024 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="4ace1812ec7d981b55a51f422287499bdacf240e7c739d50872e6de1892fa7a2"            
Mar 09 17:51:55 devnew0 kubelet[369024]: E0309 17:51:55.934416  369024 pod_workers.go:965] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"etcd\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 10s restarting failed container=etcd pod=etcd-devnew0_kube-system(419ed404bfcd79b143181759583871d1)\"" pod="kube-system/etcd-devnew0" podUID=419ed404bfcd79b143181759583871d1
```

kubectl didn't work.

```
E0309 18:06:07.103712  375368 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://162.105.85.70:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 162.105.85.70:6443: connect: connection refused
E0309 18:06:07.104510  375368 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://162.105.85.70:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 162.105.85.70:6443: connect: connection refused
E0309 18:06:07.106487  375368 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://162.105.85.70:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 162.105.85.70:6443: connect: connection refused
E0309 18:06:07.108326  375368 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://162.105.85.70:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 162.105.85.70:6443: connect: connection refused
E0309 18:06:07.110263  375368 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://162.105.85.70:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 162.105.85.70:6443: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server 162.105.85.70:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

critctl ps -a

```
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED             STATE               NAME                      ATTEMPT             POD ID              POD       
dde80047d3aff       240e201d5b0d8       34 seconds ago      Exited              kube-controller-manager   131                 fc8b51e8b4b44       kube-controller-manager-devnew0       
d4157ed07257b       63d3239c3c159       2 minutes ago       Exited              kube-apiserver            128                 96cad2187e463       kube-apiserver-devnew0                   
5910c6fb6fe53       fce326961ae2d       4 minutes ago       Exited              etcd                      134                 1fb01d0ecc4de       etcd-devnew0                                                
d635e40f9aade       6f64e7135a6ec       5 minutes ago       Exited              kube-proxy                114                 c6c2597e5097a       kube-proxy-2zmq7                                                   
e87d4f6d34e6d       db8f409d9a5d7       5 minutes ago       Exited              kube-scheduler            143                 0afe7b6d78151       kube-scheduler-devnew0
```

Comment: Check etcd container logs to see what's wrong - there should be something in `/var/log/containers`. If it's still not clear please update your question with relevant log.

Answer (score 1):

I've solve this problem.I used some deprecated fields in the /etc/containerd/config.toml, causing some nodes to work properly and others not. And thanks for your answer.